# Amazon S3 TransferUtility stops when application is closed ,even in WorkManager

Tags: android, multithreading, amazon-s3, android-workmanager

I'm using S3 TransferUtility to upload the files, the issue that i'm facing is that it stops uploading when application is closed. I want it to keep uploading running in background, for that purpose i started upload in WorkManager but still it finishes upload. What is the issue? And how is it possible to hold the workmanager from sending success result until onStatusListener asks it to. currenlty it return immediately even before file uploading starts.

```
public class TestPhotoUploadManager extends BaseWorker {

    private FileTransferUtil fileTransferUtil;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        try {
            fileTransferUtil = new FileTransferUtil();

            String filePath = getExtras().getInputData().getString(CommonTags.URL);
            if (filePath != null) {
                uploadWithTransferUtility(filePath);
            }

            return workerResult[0];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            setWorkerResult(Result.FAILURE);
            return workerResult[0];
        }
    }

    private void uploadWithTransferUtility(String filePath) {

        TransferUtility transferUtility = fileTransferUtil.getTransferUtility(getApplicationContext());

        String fileName = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf("/"));

        AppLogger.d("usm_s3_file", "name= " + fileName + " ,path= " + filePath);

        String folderName = AmazonHelper.BUCKET_NAME;

        TransferObserver uploadObserver =
                transferUtility.upload(AmazonHelper.BUCKET_NAME, folderName + fileName, new File(filePath));

        uploadObserver.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(int id, Exception e) {
                setWorkerResult(Result.FAILURE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState newState) {

                switch (newState) {
                    case WAITING_FOR_NETWORK:
                    case PENDING_NETWORK_DISCONNECT:
                        setWorkerResult(Result.RETRY);
                        break;
                    case COMPLETED:
                        setWorkerResult(Result.SUCCESS);
                        break;
                    case WAITING:
                    case IN_PROGRESS:
                        break;
                    default:
                        setWorkerResult(Result.FAILURE);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not using work-manager , different approach but the same task done.
I had a similar requirement in one of my apps, what I did was  , upload code was written in an intent service , that was scheduled to execute in some time in future(used jobscheduler for this), the upload works even when the app is closed as well as open.

Comment: The WorkManager itself passes the task to Jobscheduler, The issue is that WorkManager is not waiting for upload to be completed or cancelled, it is calling upload method and returns success.